# Intellij Idea error while importing projet from Android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, intellij-idea-2016

I am getting following error while importing project from Android Studio to Intellij Idea Professional Edition. I tried adding JAXB by importing externally but didn't work.

> Unable to load class 'javax.xml.bind.JAXBException'. Possible causes
>   for this unexpected error include: Gradle's dependency cache may be
>   corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>   Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
>
> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping
>   all Gradle daemons may solve this problem. Stop Gradle build processes
>   (requires restart)
>
> Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible
>   with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle
>   requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the
>   IDE and then killing all Java processes.

my gradle-wrapper.properties :

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: Have you tried File --> Invalidate Caches/Restart. then Rebuild ?

Comment: yes i did it as well didn't help.

Comment: Try deleting your .gradle folder and try

Comment: It does the same thing, i guess. I have done that it also didn't work.

Comment: share your  gradle-wrapper.properties file

Comment: i tried changing https to http as well, but i think the problem is different.

Comment: use [**gradlew**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) (it's in all projects at the top level gradlew --help) I suggest : **-S**,  `--full-stacktrace     Print out the full (very verbose) stacktrace for all exceptions.`
**-s**, `--stacktrace          Print out the stacktrace for all exceptions.`

Comment: @JonGoodwin, i tried as you suggested build a project by terminal using ./gradlew but it still gives same error while running on device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that in Java 12 JAXB has been removed or not compatible, I have solved the exact problem by reverting back my jdk from jdk 12 to jdk 8. Hope it helps.